# Inherit parent class attributes, __init__, etc

Tags: python, class, object

I am trying to use a parent class as a blueprint for new classes.

E.g. the `FileValidator` contains all generic attributesand methods for a generic file. Then I want to create for example a `ImageValidator` inheriting everything from the FileValidator but with additional, more specific attribtues, methods. etc. In this example the child class is called: `FileValidatorPlus`

My understanding was, that if I inherit the parent class I can just plug-in more attributes/methods without repeating anything, like just adding `min_size`. But the following code gives: `TypeError: FileValidatorPlus.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'max_size'`

```
class File:
    def __init__(self, file_size=100):
        self.file_size = file_size


class FileValidator(object):
    error_messages = {'max_size': 'some error msg'}

    def __init__(self, max_size=None):
        self.max_size = max_size

    def __call__(self, file):
        print(self.max_size > file.file_size)


class FileValidatorPlus(FileValidator):
    error_messages = {'min_size': 'some other error msg'}

    def __init__(self, min_size=None):
        super(FileValidatorPlus, self).__init__()
        self.error_messages.update(super(FileValidatorPlus, self).error_messages)

        self.min_size = min_size


validator = FileValidatorPlus(max_size=10, min_size=20)
print(validator.error_messages)
print(validator.max_size)
print(validator.min_size)
```

Full Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: FileValidatorPlus.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'max_size'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_code_executor.py", line 108, in add_exec
    more, exception_occurred = self.do_add_exec(code_fragment)
  File "/opt/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py", line 90, in do_add_exec
    command.run()
  File "/opt/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_console_types.py", line 35, in run
    self.more = self.interpreter.runsource(text, '<input>', symbol)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/code.py", line 74, in runsource
    self.runcode(code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/code.py", line 94, in runcode
    self.showtraceback()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/code.py", line 148, in showtraceback
    sys.excepthook(ei[0], ei[1], last_tb)
  File "/opt/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py", line 112, in info
    traceback.print_exception(type, value, tb)
NameError: name 'traceback' is not defined
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py", line 284, in process_exec_queue
    interpreter.add_exec(code_fragment)
  File "/opt/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_code_executor.py", line 132, in add_exec
    return more, exception_occurred
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'exception_occurred' referenced before assignment
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py", line 511, in <module>
    pydevconsole.start_server(port)
  File "/opt/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py", line 407, in start_server
    process_exec_queue(interpreter)
  File "/opt/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py", line 292, in process_exec_queue
    traceback.print_exception(type, value, tb, file=sys.__stderr__)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'traceback' referenced before assignment
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: That error doesn't match your code. You have no variable named `traceback`. Running your code gives me other errors. Make sure to create a [mcve].

Comment: Put the whole error message in, not just the last line of it. The full stack trace provide the exact location in the code where you get the error.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman ah, sorry you are right, this was part of the error. The full traceback is longer for me (need now also to find out why).

Comment: That error message seems quite bad. While the problem is that you're not providing the correct parameters to `FileValidatorPlus` (as the answers below suggests), this other error might be something to look into. It looks like there's a bug in your pycharm or python

Comment: @TedKleinBergman, thank you for your reply. Yes it seems I thought it was just one problem with the classes, but now I definetly need to have a closer look into that. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: For readers form the future: updating pycharm to `2021.3.1` solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `max_size` as a parameter in your `FileValidatorPlus` constructor.

If you want `FileValidatorPlus` to inherit this field from the super's constructor, you must not define a `__init__` method.

In other words, if you want `FileValidatorPlus` to inherit `max_size` parameter from `FileValidator`, you should delete `__init__` because the subclass only inherits constructor properties when they don't have their own constructor.

But in your case I think that it would be a better solution just to add `min_size=None` to `FileValidatorPlus.__init__`:

```
    def __init__(self, max_size=None, min_size=None):
        super(FileValidatorPlus, self).__init__(max_size)
```

Answer (score 1):

I got also different error :

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'max_size'
```

and the solution would be :

```
    def __init__(self, max_size=None, min_size=None):
        super(FileValidatorPlus, self).__init__(max_size)
```

Output:

```
{'min_size': 'some other error msg', 'max_size': 'some error msg'} 
10
20
```